# Setting element height using jquery not working in IE

Tags: jquery

```
var adjustHeight = 47*20;
$('#DivId .DivClass').css('height' , adjustHeight + 'px');
```

or

```
var adjustHeight = 47*20;
$('#DivId .DivClass').height(adjustHeight);
```

None of the above code is working in IE.

Please explain me the reason for these.
Also let me know the solution for setting height in IE.

Html Structure

```
<div id="DivId">
     <div class="DivClass">
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Height works fine in IE. There is something else wrong, and without seeing the rest of your code it's impossible to say what.

Comment: code works fine in all versions of IE, double check your code and post more info http://jsfiddle.net/pJT3j/

Comment: @Ariel : Please check the HTML structure and let me know

Comment: Ankur, can you put up a jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net ) of what you have currently? Like others, to me it looks like the problem lies elsewhere...

Comment: @AnkurMukherjee That html structure is not the problem. Height works just fine there.

Answer (score -1):

may I request you to, to check and verfiy the selectors Div and it child which u are selecting in your jQuery,

Try`$(".class .class").css({'height':'+yourvalue+'});`

EDIT: you can directly use the class name here of your child element.

`$(".class").css({'height':'+yourvalue+'});`

Comment: because setting height should be done with height() not css()